# How to create a loading indicator similar to Play Store?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm showing loading progress by using ProgressDialog.

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setTitle("Loading");
progress.setMessage("Wait while loading...");
progress.show();
```

How can I replace it with loading indicator inside current view without any popup dialog?

Something like Play Store's loading indicator.

Comment: use progress bar in your layout and set view to gone after the  operation is finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) and make it part of the Views layout. If you have an ActionBar you could use the indeterminate PrograssBar like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true)
    ...
}
```